# When I click on a drawer option in android studio, nothing happens

Tags: java, android-studio, toolbar, drawer

I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDQ-jWPw13-wY2J57Z6ep6G) tutorial series on YouTube to make a drawer for [my application](https://github.com/bluefish9981/WebHost) and I have followed everything, except I am not using fragments and instead want a toast to appear when an option from the menu is clicked and for some reason, nothing happens when I click on an option, even though I used a switch case to handle the selection of an item.

I will post the code below that way it is easier to understand my situation and if you would like you can clone the repo [here](https://github.com/bluefish9981/WebHost).

Here is the code for MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private int STORAGE_RPERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private int STORAGE_WPERMISSION_CODE = 2;
    private Button newView;
    private Button netInfo;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Context context = MainActivity.this;
        netInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.netInfo);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        Button requestPermissions = findViewById(R.id.permissions);
        requestPermissions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Permission for external storage granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Permission for external storage denied.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    requestWPermission();
                }
            }
        });

        newView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newView);
        newView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivity2();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_netInfo:
                Toast.makeText(this, "NetInfo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_savePer:
                Toast.makeText(this, "SavePer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void openActivity2()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void requestWPermission()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_WPERMISSION_CODE);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_RPERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    public void openNetworkPage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Heres the code for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/permissions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Permissions" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="code" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/netInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/newView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="openNetworkPage"
            android:text="net info" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Heres the code for drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
            android:title="About" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_netInfo"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
            android:title="Network Information" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Permissions">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_savePer"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_saveper"
                android:title="Write External" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I have gone through the tutorial twice checking my code and following the directions but still haven't found a solution to my problem. I would really appreciate it if anyone had a tip or knew what was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: The drawer in a `<DrawerLayout>` must be listed last in order to receive touch events properly. Move the `<NavigationView>` to after the `<RelativeLayout>`. I would also mention that your setup should have only one main content `View`, so you should somehow combine the `<LinearLayout>` and `<RelativeLayout>` into one; otherwise, you might have similar touch event issues elsewhere. Since you're not using `Fragment`s, you could just replace that inner `<FrameLayout>` with the `<RelativeLayout>`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you taking your time to help, I hate when it is something as simple as this.